# Custom labels associated with a contact IOS OS X Contact Framework Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, contacts, cncontact

How do I access the read-only and/or mutable contact records pertaining to what I believe to be custom labeled relationship contact data?

For instance I have Daughter-In-Law, Husband or Son custom labels associated with a contact  Do I need CNLabeledValue CNLabelContactRelationChild?  What do I need to read these or get these custom labels from contact data?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: - nadi @nadi No I did not. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I managed to do in order to assign a relation to a contact and be able to fetch it using the relation

```
var myNewContact = CNMutableContact()
let myRelation = CNContactRelation(name: "mommy")
let myMom = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelContactRelationMother, value: myRelation)
 myNewContact.contactRelations.append(myMom)

// add additional info to your contact such as name, email, family
// save your contact

let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactRelationsKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey]    
let text =  "mommy"
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
        do {
            try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(request) {
                contact, stop in
                for var i = 0; i < contact.contactRelations.count; i++ {
                    if (contact.contactRelations[i].valueForKey("value")?.valueForKey("name")!)! as? String == text
                    {
                    print(contact.givenName)
                    print(contact.identifier)
                   }
                }
            }
        } catch let err{
            print(err)
        }
    }
```

Comment: not sure yet, I am hung up on another slew of bugs, I've been reading and this looks real good to me, but I have not had a chance to test this yet.  I will  try to test soon.  Thank you so much for time and help.  I really appreciate it, and will let you know after I get to test this part.

Comment: Thank you so so much.  This totally works, I just updated it to swift 3 etc.